# Click back then next page in browser duplicates input

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, input, duplicates, back

I have this js script where I append an input when document is ready :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mydiv').append('<p><input type="text" class="form-control" /></p>');
});
```

Problem is, when I click the previous page button in my browser then the next page button, the input appears twice.

Is there a way to 'reset' the script and make it run from scratch again when doing this manipulation ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `html` method. Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mydiv').html('<p><input type="text" class="form-control" /></p>');
});
```

Comment: Can't accept your answer yet, but that's exactly what I needed thanks :) Going to accept it as soon as I can.

Comment: Thanks! Glad I was able to help.